# What is the manifold underlying the Lie group $SU(p,q)$?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I've been trying to google around this topic without success, apologies in advance if I missed an obvious resource.

I'm trying to understand what manifold (compact or not) underlies the complex Lie groups $SU(p,q)$. For example, the manifold of $SU(2,0)$ (i.e. $SU(2)$) is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$, so it's the three-sphere, or the manifold of $SU(1,1)$ is given by $x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2=1$, so it's a four dimensional hyperbolae.

EDITED QUESTION: Is there a general rule to write the system of equations that define the manifold?

Comment: Can you tell me what the manifold underlying $SU(6)$ is? I normally know it as $SU(6)$. This is no doubt true for most people and most Lie groups.

Comment: The fact you can describe each of $SU(2)$ and $SU(1,1)$ by a single equation is deceptive. More to the point, and perhaps the one general rule, is that any of these matrix groups can be described by a system of equations, to which the implicit function theorem can be applied to conclude that the solution set of the system is indeed a manifold.

Comment: I see. Then my question is rather ambiguous, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only general rule is to use the definition.

To define $SU(p,q)$, fix $A$ to be a $(p+q) \times (p+q)$ complex Hermitian matrix of signature $(p,q)$. Then you define $SU(p,q)$ to be all $(p+q) \times (p+q)$ complex matrices $M$ satisfying the following two equations:
$$M^*AM=A \quad\text{and}\quad \text{det}(M)=1
$$
If you treat the entries of $M$ as variables, and equate matrix entries in the first equation, then you get $(p+q)^2$ polynomial equations in $(p+q)^2$ variables. The second equation is one more polynomial equation in those same variables. Thus, the underlying manifold of $SU(p,q)$ is defined by a system of $(p+q)^2 + 1$ polynomial equations in the $(p+q)^2$ entries of $M$.

Comment: So, what happened for $SU(2)$ and $SU(1,1)$ in my original question was that the first $(p+q)^2$ equations fixed a parametrization of $M$ and then the determinant produced the equation for the manifold. But can't this be always achieved?

Comment: It's not accurate to assign one role to the "first $(p+q)^2$ equations" and a different role to "the determinant". Their roles are the same, namely they are part of a whole system of polynomial equations, and $SU(p,q)$ is the solution set of that system.